# i want all the files and folders in web content directory in project path, its not working by simply copying them one level up in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

In Eclipse, the folder structure when I create a Dynamic Web Project is

.:
build  src  WebContent

./build:
classes

./build/classes:

./src:

./WebContent:
index.html  META-INF  scripts  WEB-INF

./WebContent/META-INF:
MANIFEST.MF

./WebContent/scripts:
jquery-1.7.1.js

./WebContent/WEB-INF:
lib  web.xml

./WebContent/WEB-INF/lib:

As you can see, there is WebContent directory containg web-inf and other files, if I moved all the directories and files of WebContent directory a level above, it does not work,
what to do to run the index.html in eclipse

-> the directory structure after moving all the directories and files of WebContent directory a level above:

.:
build  index.html  META-INF  scripts  src  WEB-INF

./build:
classes

./build/classes:

./META-INF:
MANIFEST.MF

./scripts:
jquery-1.7.1.js

./src:

./WEB-INF:
lib  web.xml

./WEB-INF/lib:

So, now I need just go to "http://localhost:8080/Sample" and should go to index.html properly
what path changes need to be done to make it run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click the project in Eclipse and take 'Properties'
From the Dialog box, select 'Deployment Assembly'. You can change your content path from there.

Comment: what changes should i make in the following:
Source-------------Deploy Path
(1) /src---is set to---WEB-INF/classes
(2) /WebContent---is set to--- /

Comment: what changes should i make in the following: Source-------------Deploy Path (1) /src---is set to---WEB-INF/classes (2) /WebContent---is set to--- /